# why grails uses "static" vars instead of annotations

Tags: grails

for example:class

```
Book {
static mapping = {
    batchSize 10
}
}
```

could be:

```
@Configration(batchSize=10)
class Book {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I kinda like it this way. It's a lot more expressive and easier to add comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason is that Grails was developed for Groovy 1.1 which didn't support annotations. I guess one of the next versions will support annotations but as alamar said, annotations can't be changed at runtime. Therefore, the current approach is more flexible.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe because they can be changed that way?
And annotations are set in stone.